# Importing row from csv file but not the whole row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I'm importing a row from a `.csv` file into Python, it's going through ok but it's printing the whole row but I only need the first 15 cells down.

I'm now trying to break the script with a `while` statement at column 15 but cannot think of how to word it. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

So far I have the following code:

```
import csv
f=open ('example')
csv_f=csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    print(row[8]):
        while condition:
            ...
```

Comment: can you format your post? (4 spaces for code line)

Comment: Thank you all for your help and tips, question is now solved! A++++++

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over just the first 15 rows:

```
from itertools import islice
for row in islice(csv_f, 15):
    ...
```

Comment: won't really work. `csv.reader()` objects are not indexable or sliceable

Comment: Fixed that. I forgot to turn it into a list.

Comment: That's true. I'll mention that in my solution. For small files that's typically a non-issue, which is what I assume OP is dealing with.

Comment: You could also use `itertools.islice(csv_f, 15)` which is slicing the iterable without converting it to a list, would save memory and be faster

Comment: Your code is still wrong. You're trying to slice the reader object before passing it to `list()`

Answer (score 1):

```
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for line_number, row in enumerate(csv_f):
    if line_number >= 15:
        break
    print(row[8])
```

Comment: This worked a charm, thank you so much I was stressing for about an hour!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `pandas` in this case, since you probably don't want a `DataFrame`, here's how you can get a list of list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv', usecols=range(15))
mylol = df.values.tolist()
```